# 4 button title change on each click

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

Im having four buttons in my application,im getting the button title from array ,I want to change the 4 button titles whenever i click any of the button,But here the clicked button title only changed ,here my code,

```
-(IBAction)setting:(id)sender
{
int value = rand() % ([arraytext count] -1) ;
UIButton *mybuton = (UIButton *)sender;
[mybuton setTitle:[arraytext objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Updated

```
-(IBAction)answersetting:(id)sender
{

UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
static int j = 0;
if(sender == mybutton)
    j++;
if (j >= arcount)
{
    j = 0;
}
else if(j < 0)
{
    j = arcount - 1;
}

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATruncationMiddle;

[animage.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];    
animage.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];

for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||button.tag == 3||button.tag == 4)
        {
            int value = rand() % ([artext count] -1) ;
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dictionary setValue:animage.image forKey:@"button"];
            [button setTitle:[artext objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    }
}
```

}

I connect this method with 4 buttons,i want to change all button title whenever i click any of the buttons,please help to code

Comment: you need to save all these uibuttons in array then u can change the title of all these at click event.

Comment: @SHAZAD can yu explain via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sender` holds only that `UIButton` on which you have clicked.
For changing all `UIButton`'s title you need a loop.
Set `tag` to all 4 `buttons`.

Then do this -

```
-(IBAction)setting:(id)sender
{
     int value = rand() % ([arraytext count] -1) ;
     for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
     {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
            if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||button.tag == 3||button.tag == 4)
            {
                [button setTitle:[arraytext objectAtIndex:value] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }
     }  
}
```

Comment: if am having another image array how can  i show the image names as title in uibuttons

Comment: Make image names array then you can get them from array.

Comment: My doubt is how to compare if am selecting a button which contains the same image in uiimage view?

Comment: I'm not getting you correctly.You have one method of all buttons click ... then how're you doing with your imageView ?

Comment: am asking if im putting an image contained array and if showing the titles of button as image name...How could i proceed for tat?

Comment: Make a `NSMutableDictionary` and then set image Name and title in this dictionary with your button name then it would be easy for you.

Comment: `NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];`
 `[dictionary setValue:@"imageName" forKey:@"button1"];`

Comment: Add this for all for button then you get it by its key.

Comment: its not working .i update the code in my question pls help me to solve